# Couldn't find Group without an ID while destroying join table record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have users and groups joined through memberships. I am trying to implement a button that allows users to leave a group, but I keep getting the error that it cannot find the group without an id.

user.rb

```
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
```

group.rb

```
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
```

membership.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :group_id, presence: true
```

Users can join the membership just fine, that button works. The problem happens when I try to leave the group. Here is my leave button

```
<div id="join_form">
<% if current_user.groups.exists?(@group) %>
  <%= render 'memberships/leave' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'memberships/join' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

and the partial for leaving

```
<%= form_for(current_user.memberships.find_by(group_id: @group.id),
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= submit_tag "Quit #{@group.title}" %>
<% end %>
```

finally, my memberships_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @group = Group.friendly.find(params[:group_id])
    Membership.create!(user_id: @user.id, group_id: @group.id)
    redirect_to @group
  end

  def destroy
    @group = Group.friendly.find(params[:group_id])
    @membership = current_user.memberships.find_by(group_id: @group.id)
    @membership.delete
    redirect_to groups_path
  end
```

Why is the group page not passing its id?

**UPDATE:** 
I get the error on the page for the membership, which should redirect to the groups index after delete. So because it's showing the correct membership id, it must mean it knows the group id, right? So why would I be getting that error?

```
https://workspace-user.c9users.io/memberships/20
```

**UPDATE AGAIN:** The parameters are being passed correctly. I see the membership group id is 14, which allows rails to look up the membership id of 20. So why the `Couldn't find Group without an ID` message? In the console, the membership record still exists, so the deletion isn't occurring.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"njFy1J8ArpUG1qmfOVMmxpHGX/hMES7tbdGxPCn9fUHk79zcboURDKFprSA3RbGK6RNUDm8+pPjp1WFFzVBAPg==",
 "membership"=>{"group_id"=>"14"},
 "commit"=>"Quit Fitness Fam",
 "id"=>"20"}
```

Comment: `@group = Group.friendly.find(params[:membership][:group_id])`

Comment: I hate it when it's this simple. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as best.